# Closure Compiler check type on CommonJS export function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler, commonjs

I have the following files; the first file named **test.js** (entry point):

```
'use strict';
var include = require('./test.include');
console.log(include('123', 2));
```

And the second file named **test.include.js**:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Calculates the sum of a and b.
 * @param {number} a
 * @param {number} b
 * @return {number}
 */
module.exports = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Now I compile the project with Closure Compiler:

```
java -jar compiler.jar ^
--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS ^
--common_js_entry_module=test.js ^
--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT ^
--jscomp_warning=checkTypes ^
--js_output_file out.js ^
--process_common_js_modules ^
*.js
```

The compilation provides **no type error**. If I change the `module.exports` to `module.exports.sum` in the *test.include.js* and call that function, a type error is provided as expected. Is this a **bug or known problem** in closure compiler, or is there a **setting** I missed?

Comment: what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using `Version v20141120, Built on: 2014/11/21 15:12`

Comment: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues  Nick Santos did a bunch of work to make modules type check for Node.js.  I'm not sure if everything was rolled up to the main project.